# Unbind `M-o` in diff-mode with use-package

Tags: key-bindings, use-package

I'm trying to unbind `M-o` in diff-mode with `use-package`.  To do that I've written:

```lisp
(use-package diff
  :defer t
  :config
  (unbind-key "M-o" diff-mode-map))
```

Restarted Emacs 25, open a diff file, but `M-o` still seems to be mapped to  `diff-goto-source`.

I checked `diff-mode.el` and found out that there is `diff-mode-shared-map` which seems to have `M-o`.  So I did changed the map in the previous code to:

```lisp
(use-package diff
  :defer t
  :config
  (unbind-key "M-o" diff-mode-shared-map))
```

But, it still does not work.

I've used the same snippet for other modes and they seem to work as I expected. Is diff-mode special?

Comment: In the second code block you have `diff-mode-sAHred-map`, is it a mispell in your code?

Comment: Oops.  That was a typo in the question.  I should have copy & past from my init.el.  My init.el has `diff-mode-shared-map` in it.  C-h v on it works too.  Fixed in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package<sup>*</sup> name is `diff-mode`, not `diff`.  The `use-package` package symbol depends on what is `provide`d, see near the bottom of `diff-mode.el`:

```el
;; provide the package
(provide 'diff-mode)
```

> I checked `diff-mode.el` and found out that there is `diff-mode-shared-map` which seems to have `M-o`.

`diff-mode-shared-map` binds `o`, `diff-mode-map` adds an <kbd>ESC</kbd> prefix which is equivalent to `M-o`.  Therefore `diff-mode-map` is the map you want to modify.

```el
(use-package diff-mode
  :defer t
  :config
  (unbind-key "M-o" diff-mode-map))
```

Or you could unbind `o` in `diff-mode-shared-map`:

```el
(use-package diff-mode
  :defer t
  :config
  (unbind-key "o" diff-mode-shared-map))
```

This would unbind `C-c = o` in `diff-minor-mode` as well.

---

<sup>* This is not the same kind of package as a `package.el` package)</sup>